# Restarting cnosdb twice in a row will cause panic

Tags: panic, cnosdb

```
./target/release/cnosdb run --config ./config/config_31001.toml 
write some data....
```

```
killall -9 cnosdb
./target/release/cnosdb run --config ./config/config_31001.toml 
killall -9 cnosdb
./target/release/cnosdb run --config ./config/config_31001.toml
```

2023-06-27T11:18:10.072486183Z  INFO tskv::index::ts_index: index recover file: "data/db/data/cnosdb.usage_schema/3/index/_000001.binlog"
The application panicked (crashed).
Message:  called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: IndexErr { source: FileErrors { msg: "read header length 8 < 16" } }
Location: /cnosdb/tskv/src/kvcore.rs:176